# innerText -> special characters displayed incorrectly

Tags: phantomjs, character, casperjs, innertext

I'm using casperJS/phantomJS to get the inner text of div elements like this:

```
row.querySelector('.mydiv').innerText;
```

On a german page, I have problems with displaying special characters like german umlauts ( e.g. ü is displayed as Ã¼ )

What can i do to display all special characters correctly with innerText?

Thank you.

Comment: Would you please show us your CasperJS Script?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Whether it is displayed correctly in your terminal is a big issue, but it should be definitely be correctly displayed when simply written to file as is.